# How does recursion exactly work in this code?

Tags: c

How does recursion exactly work here?
I get part where "test # at the beginning" decrements but how does "test # at the end" increments?

```
# include<stdio.h>
int prod(int number);
int main(void)
{
  int x = 4;
  printf("The result of this function call is %d.\n",prod(x));
  return 0;
}


int prod(int number)
{
  int p;
  printf("test %d at the beginning\n", number);
  if(number == 1)
    return 1;
  p = (number + 1)* prod(number - 1);
  printf("test %d at the end\n", number);
  return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how things are going on:

```
1. You print value of number on beginning 
2. it is not 1 {move to line 3} else return {1}
3. you call your function prod(with value of num - 1)
4. here you have to print number again, the value of which is going to be same as line 1
```

also notice calling hierarchy:

```
prod(4) --> prod(3)--> prod(2) --> prod(1)
```

so when prod(1) returns value to prod(2), line 4 of prod(2) is still waiting to be executed.

It is executed. The value of number is 2 and hence the statement:

> test 2 at the end

then you return p to prod(3) where again line 4 is waiting to be executed.
 it is when

> test 3 at the end

is printed.

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There is one instance of `number` for each invocation of your function. It is *never* decreased inside the function, a smaller value is passed to the called one.